# Is the object_id and data_object_id only used once in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to find out which tables are actually used by the legacy application I inherited. One approach is to query `DBA_HIST_SEG_STAT`, which is based on the `object_id` and `data_object_id` of the tables/segment. There is another view `DBA_HIST_SEG_STAT_OBJ`, which can translate those ids to normal table names.

My understanding is that a table gets a new data_object_id when truncated:

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT object_id, object_name FROM all_objects;
SELECT object_id, data_object_id FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE object_name='FOO';
868066  868066

TRUNCATE TABLE foo;
SELECT object_id, data_object_id FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE object_name='FOO';
868066  868067
```

and that dropping and recreating the table assigns a new object_id:

```
DROP TABLE foo;
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT object_id, object_name FROM all_objects;
SELECT object_id, data_object_id FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE object_name='FOO';
868068  868068
```

My question is: is it safe to assume that object_id and data_object_id are unique in a database and are not recycled?

Comment: Tom Kyte says: "... any operation that radically changes the data segment - eg: truncate, alter table exchange partition, etc -- will change the data_object_id -- the data segment the object points to.".  I say: "it is never safe to assume a system-generated ID will never be reused, unless YOU wrote the system".  And even then it is iffy.  Had you considered checking for table references in any of the V$ SQL history tables?